# How do I launch a service on linux?

Tags: java, service, server

I have written server-socket Java application (not a web application) and I have a server running on Linux machine. How do I deploy this application so that I can request from anywhere from any app (assume the app has permission). Should I install eclipse/netbeans IDE on server machine and then run the code forever? Or is there any application like tomcat/xampp which will run my server code like Java/other web application.

Comment: A Java SE application (which yours seems to be) can be treated like any other application, except it depends on having the JRE installed on your target machine. At this point your question becomes "how do I launch a service on linux" which may be better answered on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Minor nitpick: the tag `java-server`, which you used, has "DON'T USE THIS TAG" written all over itself :)

Comment: Thank. I edited the question and will post it on @ServerFault

Comment: Its difficult by not knowing your actual application. As simple, you can run it by javac filename.java  or java filename (If there is class already generated ). If you also like to use tmusk as to leave server running and switch session.

Comment: *"If you also like to use tmusk as to leave server running and switch session."* or you can do the correct thing and either write a systemd unit or an init.d script, depending on the server's OS.